# minimizing the diagonal of a positive definite matrix with fixed eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \geq 0$ and set $\Lambda$ as a diagonal matrix with these eigenvalues. Consider $f(U) = \|\operatorname{diag}(U\Lambda U^T)\|_2$. Is there an intuition for how to choose an orthogonal $U$ so that $f(U)$ is minimized? To maximize $f(U)$, I think I should just set $U = I$.

For the 2x2 case, I did some experiments that suggest that $U = [[1,1],[1,-1]]$ always maximizes the quantity (regardless of $\Lambda$).

Comment: Clearly, the largest diagonal element of $U\Lambda U^T$ is bounded below by $\frac1n\sum_i\lambda_i$. Now note that this lower bound is attainable by picking an appropriate $U$ such that $U\Lambda U^T$ has a constant diagonal.

Comment: so simple - thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\|\mathrm{diag}U^T\lambda U\|_2^2=\mathrm{trace}(U^T\lambda U) ^2=\mathrm{trace}(\Lambda^2)$$ is constant with respect to $U.$

Comment: The first inequality is not true, even for a diagonal matrix